# Is it possible to use a library other than openSSL with Boost ASIO SSL support?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I would like to try using the S2N library provided by AWS Security Labs for example.

I see verbiage like this in the Boost SSL documentation:

> OpenSSL is required to make use of Boost.Asio's SSL support. When an
>   application needs to use OpenSSL functionality that is not wrapped by
>   Boost.Asio, the underlying OpenSSL types may be obtained by calling
>   ssl::context::native_handle() or ssl::stream::native_handle().

Comment: No. It's not. Look at the source, they don't seem to be layering the backend. So it's likely to remain OpenSSL for a long time.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer To be fair, they could "easily" add another ssl-stream adaptor in the same vein. But, no, there is no such competing implementation to date

Comment: @sehe ... what is ssl-stream adaptor ? Is there any documentation for it ?

Comment: @user855 here you go https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html